# Communicating with a content script in a Firefox extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have a Chrome extension which does the following action:

```js
chrome.extension.sendRequest({action: "store", working_tab: tab.id, 
                              store_text: text});
```

And Correspondingly, the listener is:

```js
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.action == "store") {
     storeObject.process();
     sendResponse({});
   }
}
```

Can you please guide me, what would be the corresponding code for a Firefox Extension? I followed the [Firefox Extension tutorial](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.7/dev-guide/tutorials/index.html) but that didn't help me much.

Appreciate, if you could post me a code snippet, so that I could start working on this.

Reason why I'm doing this: I'm trying to port this Chrome extension to Firefox.

Answer (score 4):

The equivalent code with the Firefox Add-on SDK would be something like this code:

In the main.js script, a page-mod object is created that injects a content script into a page, and also sends it a message:

```
// main add-on script
pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*.org",
  contentScriptFile: self.data.url("my-script.js"),
  // Send the content script a message inside onAttach
  onAttach: function(worker) {
    worker.port.emit("replacePage", "Page matches ruleset");
  }
});
```

In the content script, the event is received:

```
// content script
self.port.on("replacePage", function(message) {
  document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>" + message + "</h1>";
});
```

A working example can be found here:

<s>https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/addon/1053578/latest/</s>

It's important to note that, although the above example only shows communication going from the add-on to the page, the reverse is also possible - you can send messages from the content script back to the add-on using the same basic pattern of sending messages from the worker to the content script and back again. For more on how content script communication works:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.7/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/index.html