# How to convert a Chrome extension (with Chrome-specific APIs) to a Firefox add-on?

Tags: api, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, content-script

I'm having trouble converting a complex Chrome extension to a Firefox add-on. In the Chrome extension, the author uses some Chrome APIs such as

- `chrome.extension.sendMessage`
- `chrome.browserAction.setIcon`
- `webkitNotifications.createNotification`
- `chrome.tabs.sendMessage`
- `chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener`
- `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener`
- `chrome.privacy.services.autofillEnabled.get`
- `chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener`
- `chrome.tabs.query`
- `localStorage`

and so on.

I don't know how to implement these methods in Firefox add-on code.  Some of these APIs can be called with a call-back function. For example:

```js
chrome.extension.sendMessage ( {
        type: "get.identitieswithurl",
        originUrl: lgmIdentitySave.originUrl,
        actionUrl: lgmIdentitySave.actionUrl
    }, 
    function (resultIdentities) {
        if(resultIdentities != null && resultIdentities.length > 0) {
            lgmIdentitiesPage = resultIdentities;
            fillFormsWithCredential(resultIdentities[0]);
            if(resultIdentities.length > 1 && lgmSuggestionSelectIdDismissed == false) {
                showSelectIdentitySuggestionBar();
            }
        }
    } 
);
```

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107921/communicating-with-a-content-script-in-a-firefox-extension), I know that the Firefox code can be written like

```js
// main add-on script
pageMod.PageMod({
    include: "*.org",
    contentScriptFile: self.data.url("my-script.js"),
    // Send the content script a message inside onAttach
    onAttach: function (worker) {
        worker.port.emit("replacePage", "Page matches ruleset");
    }
});
```

But I still don't know how to add the callback function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's go through your list. Throughout the answer, I will refer to the relevant [documentation](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/index.html). If you're complelely clueless on getting started with Firefox add-on development, read the [Getting started](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/tutorials/index.html#getting-started) tutorial.

Before starting, also read about [modules](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/modules.html) and the [SDK Idioms](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/index.html#sdk-idioms) (the last one is very important, because it gives an explanation on important concepts in the Firefox add-on SDK world).

- `chrome.extension.sendMessage` / `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` / 
  `chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener`
  See [Content scripts](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/index.html#content-scripts) to learn how to work with the [`sdk/page-mod`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/page-mod.html) module and pass around messages.
- `chrome.browserAction.setIcon`  and `chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener`
  I've written a SDK module which is a full implementation of Chrome's [`chrome.browserAction`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html) API for Firefox. Installation instructions and documentation is found at https://github.com/Rob--W/browser-action-jplib.
- `webkitNotifications.createNotification`
  See the [`sdk/notifications`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/notifications.html) module.
- `chrome.privacy.services.autofillEnabled.get`
  See `sdk/preferences/service` module. A list of preference identifiers can be found at the [about:config entries](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_:_FAQs_:_About:config_Entries) article. For your specific example:

  ```
  var prefName = 'browser.formfill.enable';
  var prefService = require("sdk/preferences/service");
  var isAutoFillEnabled = prefService.get(prefName); // true or false
  ```
- `chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener`
  Whether your extension was installed can be determined by reading the [`loadReason` property of the `self` module](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/self.html#loadReason), e.g.

  ```
  if (require('sdk/self').loadReason == 'install') {
      // Do something on the very first install
  }
  ```
- `chrome.tabs.query`
  The [`sdk/tabs`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/tabs.html) module is an iterator. You can loop through the object and filter out the results yourself.
- `localStorage`
  See [`sdk/simple-storage`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/simple-storage.html)

Comment: will the firefox add-on that developed with addon builder provide the same function as chrome extension?

Comment: @dapengalways If you implement it correctly, yes. Firefox add-ons are actually more powerful than Chrome extensions, because Firefox add-ons are trusted by Firefox, and run at the same privilege level.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.the main.js(it may require other module) part in the firefox is just like the background part of chrome extension,am I right?so when the background part in the chrome extension has many js files,correspondingly,in the firefox add-on,we should change these js files into main.js's module,the main.js will be called when the browse opens.Right?

Comment: @dapengalways A significant difference between Firefox's main.js vs Chrome's background.js is that main.js does not have any associated document (DOM). If you want to use an external library in Firefox's main.js, it has to export its API through a `exports` object and then `require`d in main.js. See the link to modules in my answer for a more thorough explanation.

Comment: @dapengalways `chrome.extension.onmessage` has been mentioned again at the browserAction section because I've actually implemented Chrome's message API for Firefox. See lib/messaging.js in my Github repository. The reason for showing Firefox's way of communication is to equip you with the ability to understand and use a commonly used pattern in Firefox's add-on SDK.

Comment: That's a good message.Does that mean I can use `chrome.extension.onmessage` without using Firefox add-on api if I import browserAction.js and messaging.js to main.js?

Comment: @dapengalways Have you installed the addon-sdk? If yes, run cfx sdocs, then run cfx docs to open the documentation. At the Third Party modules section, you'll see the documentation for the messaging API, generated from https://github.com/Rob--W/browser-action-jplib/blob/master/docs/messaging.md.

Comment: Thank you for your implemented API and I have met another problem that says `ReferenceError: extension is not defined` when I use your API `extension.*`.  I have required the needed file in my main.js.

Comment: @dapengalways `extension.` is not a globally available identifier. See the example in [the documentation](https://github.com/Rob--W/browser-action-jplib/blob/master/docs/messaging.md): You need to create the channel using `var extension = createMessageChannel(pagemod.contentScriptOptions, worker.port);` in the `onAttach` event.

Comment: I know. I have defined the `extension` in the `onAttach`,then can I use the extension in my content scripts?

Comment: @dapengalways I have updated the library to include that feature. Add `endAtPage:false` at the `contentScriptOptions` to make the "extension" object available to the content script. Make sure that my module is loaded before all of your other content scripts.

Comment: What about onConnect? Do firefox support similar API?

Comment: @pvnarula The addon SDK has [ports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts#Communicating_with_the_add-on).